# MatLab returns eigenvectors/generalized eigenvectors that do not match an example on Wikipedia?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

On the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Example_1) on generalized eigenvectors it uses the example of a matrix $A$ given by
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and says that this matrix has a repeated eigenvalue of $1$ with multiplicity $2$, and that the eigenvector $v_1$ and generalized eigenvector $v_2$ are given by
$$
v_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
v_2  =
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $a$ can be any scalar. However when I create this matrix in MatLab and use $\texttt{eig}$ to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors I get the repeated eigenvalue of $1$ but the eigenvectors/generalized eigenvector it gives me are
$$
v_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
v_2  =
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

```
A = [ 1, 1; 0, 1]
[V, D] = eig(A)
```

So why is MatLab not returning eigenvectors that match the Wikipedia example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple: `eig` finds only eigenvectors, not generalized eigenvectors.

---

The vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is not a eigenvector of $A$, it is only a generalized eigenvector of $A$, so there is no reason you would expect for `eig` (a function which finds eigenvectors) to find it.

---

To quote from [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html):

> `[V,D] = eig(A)` returns diagonal matrix `D` of eigenvalues and matrix `V` whose columns are the corresponding right eigenvectors, so that `A*V = V*D`.